# stability patterns

Tags: architecture

I have read that there are stability patterns for software.

Can someone list them or refer to a book or some other resources?

regards

Comment: To anyone else that has not heard of SSM 'Software Stability Model (SSM) [1] is a software development technique that designed to improve software qualities like stability, reusability, scalability, understandability, reusability and simplicity'

Comment: What are you really looking for? Most of those principles are just generic principles and there are other good resources out there that can help you in producing better systems?

Answer (score 6):

["Release It!: Design and Deploy Production-Ready Software"](http://pragprog.com/titles/mnee/release-it) by Michael T. Nygard.

I really enjoyed reading it.